# AllowEditRanges not working with looping through worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first time working through using alloweditranges in vba. I have a workbook that has 20+ worksheets. There are 4 ranges that need to allow the user to update on each worksheet name stored in the variable tabNames. The rest of the worksheet is mostly formulas.

I worked on the following code, but for some reason, it throws a run-time error 13: type mismatch on the first line after the For each loop. Any help would be appreciated. There are a lot of worksheets and I don't want to have to do it manually for each worksheet.

```
wb1.Sheets(cell).Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Budget1", Range:=("B9,B12:B26,B32:B38,B42:B58,B62:B70,B73:B76,B83:B91")
```

I also would like to know for the ranges, is there a way for the range to dynamically be stored. The data will always be between rows 9 and 101, in the same columns, but i need it to skip blanks & formulas.

```
Sub alloweditrangesmacro()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim tabNames As Variant
    Dim cell As Variant
    
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
        
    lastrow = wb1.Sheets("Start Here").Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
    tabNames = wb1.Sheets("Start Here").Range("R2:R" & lastrow).Value
    
    For Each cell In tabNames
       wb1.Sheets(cell).Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Budget1", Range:=("B9,B12:B26,B32:B38,B42:B58,B62:B70,B73:B76,B83:B91")
       wb1.Sheets(cell).Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Budget2", Range:=("I9,I12:I26,I32:I38,I42:I58,I62:I70,I73:I76,I83:I91")
       wb1.Sheets(cell).Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Prior1", Range:=("D9,D12:D26,D32:D38,D42:D58,D62:D70,D73:D76,D83:D91")
       wb1.Sheets(cell).Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Prior2", Range:=("K9,K12:K26,K32:K38,K42:K58,K62:K70,K73:K76,K83:K91")
       wb1.Sheets(cell).Protect
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing a Range - `Range:=Range("B9,B12:B26,B32:B38,B42:B58,B62:B70,B73:B76,B83:B91")`

Comment: @SJR thank you. do i need to set the edit ranges everytime i protect & unprotect the worksheets?

Comment: I'm not sure but I doubt it if you save the file.